# Bash script kill not working

Tags: bash, kill

`#name -  name of killing process`

`pidof name | kill`

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Any errors or anything, if you run in terminal?  Please, help us to help you.

Comment: You can also use `killall name`

Answer (score 9):

`kill` doesn’t seem to read PIDs from STDIN (which is fed when you pipe the output of `pidof` to it).

This should work:

```
kill $(pidof name)
```

For less typing you can also use the following (as suggested by @florian-diesch in the comments):

```
pkill name
```

Comment: You can just use `pkill gedit` instead.